# C# IDE error code

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ide

I'm coding four C# files and I'm linking the classes.
The problem is I used Ubuntu in Virtual box to debug and I'm now building in a different IDE.
Needless to say there are several error messages which I have no problems with.
The one that bugs me is the error I get from the following code:

```
static bool Interphase(int argc, string[] args)

{
  return kernel_main(argc, args, GlobalMembersHANNAH.L4work_E4dorq_A7concept_hinfo);
}
```

The system does not recognize the 'kernel_main' which I must admit I did not code for...
It was generated as I debugged in Ubuntu so I assume it's associated with a Linux file.
My question is how do I initialize the:

```
public static class GlobalMembersHANNAH
```

in another file in this one.
Please note all four files share the same namespace.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Static classes can't be initialized. Remove the `static` keyword if you need it to be initializable.